# Comparing two arraylists and then adding matches to specific text files

Tags: java

I have two `arraylists` of names. I am trying to compare the two. If the name in the first array equals the name in the second array, I want to create a text file that is called "name j" where j is the index the matching name is found. Right now it seems to be able to find two of the matching names but not the last one. I am not sure why it is not finding the last one.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList <String> names = new ArrayList ();
        names.add("Stephen");
        names.add("James");
        names.add("Billy");
        names.add("Connor");
        names.add("Katie");

        ArrayList <String> names2 = new ArrayList();
        names2.add("Carlos");
        names2.add("Katie");
        names2.add("James");
        names2.add("Cameron");
        names.add("Blly");

        int i,j;
        i=0;
        j=0;

        int nameSize = names.size();
        int names2Size = names2.size();
        int checkMatches=0;
       // boolean endOfList = false;

        while (i<nameSize)  {
            if (names.get(i).equals(names2.get(j))) {
                //increase i b/c of match
                System.out.println("Match " + names.get(i));
                infoToFile(j,i,names);
                i++;
            } else if (j == names2Size-1) {
                System.out.println("No Match");
                i++;
                j=0;
            } else  {
                System.out.println("No Match");
                j++;
            }
        }

public static  void infoToFile(int j,int i,ArrayList <String> names)    {
        Writer output;
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("name " + j + ".txt",true));
            output.append(names.get(i) + "\n");
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RosterPractice.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do this by many different ways, but I will show you how  I did (and test it):

1st you need to check which list is bigger than other, otherwise you will get a indexOutOfBoundsException
after that, do a for over the smallest list, check if the string are the same if this is met, call the method to create a file and pass as parameter then name of the file to crete (I did it passing index and name, but you could do it by passing a concatenation of those too)

## an example of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Stephen");
    names.add("Sepp");
    names.add("James");
    names.add("Billy");
    names.add("Connor");
    names.add("Katie");
    System.out.println(names);

    List<String> names2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    names2.add("Carlos");
    names2.add("Sepp");
    names2.add("Katie");
    names2.add("James");
    names2.add("Cameron");
    names2.add("Blly");
    names2.add("Xoce");
    names2.add("Marie");
    System.out.println(names2);

    if (names.size() > names2.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < names2.size(); i++) {
            if (names.get(i).equals(names2.get(0))) {
                createFile(i, names.get(0));
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            if (names.get(i).equals(names2.get(i))) {
                createFile(i, names.get(1));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void createFile(int i, String name) {
    File f = new File(name + "_" + i);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you posting two answers?